# Volley get request doesn't hit server

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I am around this issue it already past like 2 hours, basicly i am trying to get some data from my server and the volley callback never get executed.

Basicly i have an interface defined to handle the volley request, so for the getRequest i have something like this:

```
public void getDataObjectVolley(final String requestType, String url, final String token){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("tokenXX",token);
                    headers.put("x-access-token", token);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

then on my activity i intialize the callback and pass the functions to him:

```
IResult mResultCallbackGET = null;
```

**onCreate i call the loadPhotos**

```
 loadPhotoDetails();
```

**then the method is like this:**

```
 private void loadPhotoDetails() {
        final String urlDetails = connectionTxt + "/fotos/" + fotoId;
        loadPhotoInfo();
        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallbackGET,this);
        mVolleyService.getDataObjectVolley(GETREQUEST,urlDetails,token);
    }
```

**the loadPhotoInfo**

```
void loadPhotoInfo(){
        Log.d("HELLOWORLD","HELLOWOLD");
        mResultCallbackGET = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
                /*Log.d("HELLOWOLRD","HELLOWOLD1");
                Log.d("resposta123",response.toString());
                String path = null;
                Double lat = null;
                Double lon = null;
                Double alt = null;
                Boolean hasFlower = null;
                Boolean hasLeaf = null;
                Boolean hasThorn = null;
                Boolean hasFruit = null;
                String flowerColor = null;
                String time = null;

                try {
                    path = response.getString("image");
                    lat = response.getDouble("lat");
                    lon = response.getDouble("lon");
                    alt = response.getDouble("altitude");
                    hasFlower = response.getBoolean("hasFlower");
                    hasLeaf = response.getBoolean("hasLeaf");
                    hasThorn = response.getBoolean("hasThorn");
                    hasFruit = response.getBoolean("hasFruit");
                    flowerColor = response.getString("flowerColor");
                    time = response.getString("date");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                photoDetails = new Photo(path,lat,lon,alt,time,hasFlower,hasLeaf,hasThorn,hasFruit,flowerColor);
                Log.d("fruit12",String.valueOf(hasFlower));
                Log.d("fruit12",String.valueOf(hasLeaf));
                Log.d("fruit12",String.valueOf(hasThorn));

                if(hasFruit){
                    hasFruitTxt.setText("Sim");
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("fruit","false");
                    hasFruitTxt.setText("Não");
                }

                if(photoDetails.getHasFlower()){
                    hasFlowerTxt.setText("Sim");
                }
                else{
                    hasFlowerTxt.setText("Não");
                }

                if(photoDetails.getHasThorns()){
                    hasThornsTxt.setText("Sim");
                }
                else{
                    hasThornsTxt.setText("Não");
                }

                if(photoDetails.getHasLeaf()){
                    hasLeafTxt.setText("Sim");
                }
                else{
                    hasLeafTxt.setText("Não");
                }*/
                Log.d("HELLOWOLRD","HELLOWOLD1");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("HELLOWOLRD","HELLOWOLD2");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("HELLOWOLRD","HELLOWOLD3");
            }
        };
    }
```

you guys can see that i have 4 hello worlds log, it just enters the first, it never hits the server, any help with this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is handle all your HTTP requests in the loadPhotoDetails() method. Code will be shorter. You can create a CONSTANTS file to handle connectionTxt and other constants. (Refer to example below)

//--------------------------------------------------------

private void loadPhotoDetails()(String fotoId) {

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            connectionTxt + "/fotos/" + fotoId, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                if (response.has("Ratings")) {
                    JSONArray ratings = response.getJSONArray("Ratings");

                    String source = null;
                    String value = null;
                    if (ratings.length() > 0) {

                        JSONObject mRatings = ratings.getJSONObject(ratings.length() - 1);
                        source = mRatings.getString("Source");
                        value = mRatings.getString("Value");
                        rating.setText(source + " : " + value);

                    }else {
                        rating.setText("Ratings: N/A");
                    }

                    path.setText(response.getString("image"));
                    lat.setText(response.getString("lat"));
                    lon.setText(response.getString("lon"));
                    alt.setText(response.getString("altitude"));
                    hasFlower.setText(response.getBoolean("hasFlower"));
                    hasLeaf.setText(response.getBoolean("hasLeaf"));
                    hasThorn.setText(response.getBoolean("hasThorn"));
                    hasFruit.setText(response.getBoolean("hasFruit"));
                    flowerColor.setText(response.getString("flowerColor"));
                    time.setText(response.getString("date"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error:", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

//-----------------------------------------